# What does the word "only" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a part of a dialogue between two characters that I was reading in my [book](https://www.successcds.net/cce-cbse/class-xii/english/on-the-face-of-it.html):

> *Mr Lamb*: You could tell me your name. If you chose. And not, if you didn't.
>
> *Derry*: Derry. Only it's Derek.... but I hate that. **Derry.** If I am your friend, you don't have to be mine. I choose that.

What does the word "only" mean in this context? And the second thing I want to ask is why Derry retells his name (the highlighted part)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In context, **only** means **actually** or **however**.

Derry is telling Mr. Lamb that his real name is Derek, but that he prefers to be called Derry.  His repetition of the name, *"Derry"*, is to reiterate his preference.

See also **[only](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/only)**, specifically the definition where **only** is used a *conjunction*.